# Do monster templates still exist in post-Essentials D&D 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters

In the D&D 4e Monster Manual, there are monster templates such as 'lich' which increase a standard monster to elite or an elite to a solo.

Do monster templates still appear in more recent core D&D material?

Comment: Monster Templates can be found in the DMG, Monster Manuals or Open Grave. These templates are recommened for monster but you can apply them to Player Characters with caution.

Also, even intelligent artifacts/items surve as templates.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, templates are still being published

Page 117 of the ***Neverwinter Campaign Gudie*** has a Wererat template.

Interestingly, unlike the templates in the original core products, it does not make the monster an elite.

Futhermore, this ***Book of Vile Darkness*** [preview article](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ex/20111121) presents a Moilian Dead monster theme, which has a lot in common with monster templates (the key difference being DM choice in picking theme powers from a menu).